# Second Run of a Function

Tags: python, function, pandas, series

I got a script which declares a variable and sets it to a pandas Series object.

```
Pi = pd.Series(0, index=[some_index])
```

then a for loop adds more values to that pandas Series object:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
        Pi = Pi.add(some_value[i], fill_value=0)
```

the thing I want to code is a function which I can put inside this for loop, like:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
        Pi = my_function()
```

but the problem is my_function() should declare a pandas series object at first run (return pd.Series(0)) and after the first run, it should somehow change and add new values (return pd.add(some_value)) instead of defining pd.Series(0) again.

Ty

Comment: This workflow seems incorrect. You probably don't want to build the Series at all until you've created a list with everything that you wish to put in it.

Comment: imagine a series with 3 columns and 10 raws? I can't put it to a list

Comment: This whole thing looks like an anti pattern (initializing a Series / adding some numbers to it in a loop). Can you give more details about what you are trying to do? Your example is vague because you can definitely achieve the same thing with `sum(some_value)`.

Comment: just imagine I got a series object from an other function, and i want to add them on next iteration, but to be able add them together, I need an empty series object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this as it has no benefits and is confusing.

```
def my_function(Pi, i):
    if i == 0: # First iteration, Create the Series
        Pi = pd.Series(0, index=[some_index])

    Pi = Pi.add(some_value[i], fill_value=0)
    return Pi

Pi=None
for i in range(0, 10):
    Pi = my_function(Pi, i)
```

Perhaps a class is what you want:

```
class PiSeries:

    def __init__(self, some_index):
        self.Pi = pd.Series(0, index=[some_index])

    def my_function(self, i):
        self.Pi = self.Pi.add(some_value[i], fill_value=0)

    def create_series(self, start, end):
        for i in range(start, end):
            self.my_function(i)

        return self.Pi

PiSeries(index=some_index).create_series(start=0, end=10)
```

Comment: a class is definitely not I want, but your first suggestion seem nice, got a question though: is there anyway calling my function without giving the argument Pi?

Comment: No, not unless you declare Pi somewhere else. It's state would be lost whenever you call the function otherwise :/ Also about not using classes, just consider this if you come from other languages: In python, everything is a class, even an int or a string :)

Comment: by the way second run of my_function gives an Error: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." 2nd run on "if not Pi" causes this most likely...

Comment: Updated answer.